# env-cmd error failed to locate ./.env file in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file name .env.development in the root folder. I had install env-cmd as dev dependencies
when I start the server

```
  > npm run develop
```

its give me an error

```
> gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop I:\learngatsby
> env-cmd .env-development gatsby develop

(node:1368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to locate env file at default location (./.env)
at I:\learngatsby\node_modules\env-cmd\dist\get-env-vars.js:44:19
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at rejected (I:\learngatsby\node_modules\env-cmd\dist\get-env-vars.js:5:65)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

```
(node:1368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:1368) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: maybe only works if the name is `.env` not `.env-development` or `.env.development`

Comment: No it did not working

Comment: Why do you have `.env-development` in the error but the file name in the root is `.env.development` ?

Comment: I think you are taking about this line in console "env-cmd .env-development gatsby develop", it is not an error. It is just console view . Error statment started from fourth line

Comment: if your file name is `env.development` shouldn't the command be `env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop` and not `env-cmd .env-development gatsby develop`

Comment: No my file name is .env.development not env.development

Comment: I made a mistake. I meant if your file name is `.env.development` shouldn't the command be `env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop`?

Comment: ok  this "env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop" already included in package.json file under scripts object

Comment: I couldn't get the env file loading so I just put the variable into the package.json file ```"develop": "GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop",```

Comment: I had the same issue on Mac OS Catalina with .env files. Somehow, I had created a file called env.env that was interfering, I deleted it, stayed only with .env and the problem was gone. That was my experience.

Answer (score 73):

You can set environment variable using your own custom `.env` files with `-f` flag with `env-cmd`. Use this command to set `env` variables that are defined in custom file `'./config/myvar.env'`.

`env-cmd -f ./config/myvar.env`

For more information use this [link](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd)

Answer (score 42):

This has been updated in the latest version of env-cmd, if you are using version <9.0.0 then it will work perfectly but with version >9.0.0 the default environment file it will look for is .env

use `env-cmd -f .env.development gatsby develop` instead, here -f is provided for custom file name.

Answer (score 35):

Add `-f` to your `package.json` file

```
"develop": "env-cmd -f .env.development gatsby develop",
```

Answer (score 13):

You can rename `.env.development` to just `.env` and then run `env-cmd gatsby develop`, this will look for environment variables inside `.env` file.

You can also update the `develop` node script inside the `package.json` like the following:

```
"develop": "env-cmd gatsby develop"
```

Then you can run the node script,

```
npm run develop
```

or

```
gatsby develop
```

Answer (score 8):

use the -f flag  and make sure the path to your .env.development file is correct.

```
"develop": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development gatsby develop"
```

Answer (score 7):

In Windows. 
First create file `.env.development`
Then add in package.json:
`"develop": "env-cmd -f .env.development --fallback gatsby develop"`
and: `npm run develop`
attached: [https://css-tricks.com/using-graphql-playground-with-gatsby](https://css-tricks.com/using-graphql-playground-with-gatsby/)

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue, here's a snippet of gatsby-config.js I added to make the ".env.development" file visible to gatsby. (Not sure if this is the only way, node/Gatsby experts please chime in)

```
let activeEnv =
  process.env.GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"

console.log('Using environment config: ${activeEnv}')

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Based on this gatsby-config.js, here is the develop script in package.json (unchanged) -

```
...
"develop": "gatsby develop",
...
```

Finally, starting the gatsby app using

```
npm run develop
```

, the logs mentions playground being available -

```
You can now view gatsby-starter-hello-world in the
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/
⠀
View the GraphQL Playground, an in-browser IDE, to
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/___graphql
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:
First run the command: `npm install --save-dev env-cmd@10.1.0`

Step 2:
Replace `env-cmd .env-development gatsby develop` with `./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./.env.development gatsby develop`

Answer (score 3):

Add `-f` to your `package.json` file.

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js"
```

Comment: Adding -f worked for me. Can you please explain why is it required. Is it override default settings or something ?

Comment: @PavithraB please read the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd#using-custom-env-file-path

Answer (score 0):

Adding the let snippet to the gatsby-config.js file did the trick for me! And then starting up with gatsby develop
Tnx! Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. 
This solves it for me

```
"develop": "env-cmd --file .env.development --fallback gatsby develop",
```

and pass in this value .env.development file `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground`.

In case, you want to understand how to set it up better, You can check out this article 
on CSS Tricks by 
[Adebiyi Adedotun](https://css-tricks.com/using-graphql-playground-with-gatsby)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,

i tried below code

```
env-cmd -f ./config/myvar.env
```

its not working for me.

Instead i add full path of config folder like below and its works like charm..!!!!

```
env-cmd -f fullPath/config/myvar.env
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case got this error :

*`Error: Failed to find .env file at path: .env.local at getEnvFile (E:\project\....)`*

Then i just rename *`.env.development`* file to *`.env.local`* and it is working fine.

or if you are working on remote git repository then check you have pulled latest changes made by your team member to your local dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works having `.env` file with following scripts for develop inside the `package.json`.

```
"develop": "env-cmd gatsby develop"
```