# Gatsby’s Environmental Variables "env.cmd not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, gatsby

Trying to run env.cmd with Gatsby but I'm getting `sh: env-cmd not found`. I do have installed the package. I have tried deleting `.node-modules` and running `npm install` but I'm still getting the same error.

gatsby-config.js:

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "env-cmd --file .env.development --fallback gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.26",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
...
}
```

Terminal:

```
npm run develop

> gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop /Users/renatognunes/Documents/Studies 1:4/Gatsby/gatsby-site
> env-cmd --file .env.development --fallback gatsby develop

sh: env-cmd: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop: `env-cmd --file .env.development --fallback gatsby develop`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**UPDATE**
For anyone else running into the same issue, here is the solution I found that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367980/10225590

Comment: If you do `env-cmd` in your shell is it defined? Seems like it's not properly added to your PATH

Comment: How would I solve this issue? Any reference? @QuantumLicht

Comment: Here is the solution for anyone else running into the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [env-cmd error failed to locate ./.env file in gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301852/env-cmd-error-failed-to-locate-env-file-in-gatsby)

Comment: No @ksav I have updated my question with the solution that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my npm version to v16.3.1 from v14.18.3 fixed this for me

Comment: I think you are talking about your `node` version instead of `npm`

Answer (score 0):

This is a Node version issue. Could you try checking your node version?

> `node -v`

It might be the latest version you are currently using like `v18.24.1`

If it is not try changing your node version to a couple of popular node versions and try installing the modules.

> `nvm ls -l` to check the node versions available

> `nvm use <expected node version you need here>`

- Delete `node_modules` & `package-lock.json` before running `npm i`